# Django- Insert Data To Model Field

Tags: django, django-models

First Of All:

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

user = User()

for field in User._meta.fields:
    user.field.name = 'John' # here is my problem
```

But I Can't Insert "John" To first_name Or last_name.

How Can I Say `user` That `field.name` Is Name Of Field????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it out, and ._meta.fields returns the id field too.

To do what you want you can:

```
for field in User._meta.fields:
  setattr(user, field.name, 'John')
```

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr

Comment: And Hou Can I Add Object If The Field Is ManyToManyField. How Can I Do It?

Comment: for field in user._meta.many_to_many,  You need to save the object before you specify many-to-many relationship

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you would even want to do this, but here's the best approximation of what I think you want.

```
for field in User._meta.fields:
    if field.name == 'first_name':
        setattr(user, field.name, 'John')
```